# How to combine together randomly the characters of two strings in C?

Tags: c, string, char

Given this homework:
Write a function which has 3 parameters: The first two will be combined in the 3rd.
Example: `s1=”abcde”`, `s2=”1234567”`, and the result:  `s3=”a1b2c3d4e567”`.

My code looks like this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int homework(char a[], char b[])
{
char c[210]={'0'};
int h1=strlen(a);
int h2=strlen(b);
int i=0;
int j;
int db=0;
int l=0;
while ( h1>=0 && h2>=0 )
{
  db++;
  c[i]=a[l];
  c[i+1]=b[l];

  h2--;
  h1--;
  i+=2;
  l++;

  }
h1++;
h2++;


printf("%d %d",h1,h2);

if (h1>0){
i--;
while (h1>0)
{
  c[i]=a[l];
  l++;
  i++;
  h1--;


}
}


if (h2>0){
i--;
while (h2>0)
{
  c[i]=a[l];
  l++;
  i++;
  h2--;
}

}

 for (j=0; j<strlen(a)+strlen(b); j++)
printf("%c",c[j]);


}




int main()
{
char a[100],b[100];

gets(a);
gets(b);
homework(a,b);


return 0;
}
```

The problem is it only works when the length of the the two strings are equal.

Comment: You have to show us what you have attempted so far before we can help you with your problem.

Comment: You really really really should also pass in the size available for parameter 3. `int combine(const char *src1, const char *src2, char *dst, size_t len);`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show your attemps - in the form of code - to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have added my code.

Comment: May I see your solution @RoiHatam ?

Comment: And is there any specific button here that can repost my question or create a total new one and copy-paste the details from here? :D

Comment: Please click edit below the question. You need to fix the indention/code formatting, since the code is currently quite unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
    void    Homework(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  int   i;
  int   j;
  int   k;
  char *str3;

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  k = 0;
  str3 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)) + 1);
  while (strlen(str3) != strlen(str1) + strlen(str2))
    {
      if (k % 2 == 0 && str1[i] != 0)
        {
          str3[k] = str1[i];
          i++;
        }
      else if (k % 2 == 1 && str2[j] != 0)
        {
          str3[k] = str2[j];
          j++;
        }
      else if ((i + 1) > strlen(str1))
        {
          str3[k] = str2[j];
          j++;
        }
      else if ((j + 1) > strlen(str2))
        {
          str3[k] = str1[i];
          i++;
        }
      k++;
    }
  printf("Your combine string is: %s. \n", str3);
}
```